# Angular stateprovider redundant nested states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a weird situation where I have redundant nested states, let me explain.

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
                templateUrl: env.clientBaseUrl + 'dashboard/templates/dashboard.html',
                controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
            }).state('dashboard.detail', {
                url: '/detail',
                pageTitle: 'Detail',
                templateUrl: env.clientBaseUrl + 'common/templates/detail.html',
                controller: 'detailCtrl'
             }).state('application', {
                url: '/application:id',
                pageTitle: 'Application',
                templateUrl: env.clientBaseUrl + 'application/templates/application.html',
                controller: 'applicationCtrl'
            }).state('application.detail', {
                url: '/detail',
                pageTitle: 'Detail',
                templateUrl: env.clientBaseUrl + 'common/templates/detail.html',
                controller: 'detailCtrl'
             }).state('users', {
                url: '/users:id',
                pageTitle: 'Users',
                templateUrl: env.clientBaseUrl + 'users/templates/users.html',
                controller: 'usersCtrl'
            }).state('users.detail', {
                url: '/detail',
                pageTitle: 'Detail',
                templateUrl: env.clientBaseUrl + 'common/templates/detail.html',
                controller: 'detailCtrl'
             });
```

As in above states, there are multiple states whose child state is detail.
So how could I make sure that the redundant child states are not repeated for multiple states and there is a single child state for all the states due to redundant code, 
its hard to maintain and debug also make changes in all redundant places (like adding a resolve etc.)

Comment: does each of your detail states (user.detail, dashboad.detail) going to do the same thing or completely different stuffs? You are using the same template , but are the controllers gonna be the same too?

Comment: Yes, each of the states are going to do the same thing and same controllers as well

Comment: If you have a controller that does the **SAME** thing, why don't just declare a state called `detail` instead of nesting each of them?